# How can I specify the line thickness of reused elements in an SVG document?

Tags: svg, graphics

I have an SVG document which contains a scaled group which is defined in the `<defs>...</defs>` section.

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="pADC3" >
        <rect x="-3142" y="1328" width="10411" height="6610" />
    </clipPath>
  <g id=model">
    <line id="i22" class="ELECTRICAL" x1="-3142" y1="-1328" x2="7269" y2="7938" stroke="magenta"/>
    <rect x="-3142" y="1328" width="10411" height="6610" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
    ...
  </g>
</defs>
```

If I scale this defined group and place it in the document:

```
<use id="iADC3" class="lVPORT" href="#model" transform="translate(171 108) scale(0.050000)" clip-path="url(#pADC3)" />
```

...it doesn't show.

If I increase the line thickness (stroke-width) to 50, only then the lines show.

Furthermore, any lines drawn within the rest of the document are at different thicknesses.

Is there a way of defining a line thickness for a scaled group?

Comment: If you scale the line by 0.05 then you're making it pretty thin, that's why you need the stroke width to be large to counter that. 0.05 x 50 = 2.5. You can use vector-effects="non-scaling-stroke" if you don't want the stroke-width to scale at all.

Comment: That sounds like the ideal solution. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. Where does the vector-effects directive go? I've tried putting it in the `<g vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">` and in the `<path>` element, but neither Firefox nor Chrome show any difference.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect

Comment: Note that vector-effect is not an inherited property so if you set it on a <g> you'd have to set all the children to vector-effect="inherit" explicitly (or do so via CSS)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although the syntax checker at https://validator.w3.org/nu/ reports errors: `Attribute vector-effect not allowed on SVG element g at this point.
<g id="model" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="50">`. It also doesn't like the attribute in the `<line>` tag or in the `<path>` tag.

Comment: That validator has not been maintained for more than 10 years now.